# How can I interact with javascript website with java

Tags: java, javascript

I would like to type some text in textfield, and then select a, if a is not available, then select b, finally submit the information.
  I just write these code and get no idea what can I do next.

```
URL page_1 = new URL("https://google.com.hk");
HttpURLConnection urlconnection = (HttpURLConnection) page_1.openConnection();

DataOutputStream data_out = new DataOutputStream(urlconnection.getOutputStream());
DataInputStream data_in = new DataInputStream(urlconnection.getInputStream());

urlconnection.setDoInput(true);
urlconnection.setDoOutput(true);

System.out.println(data_out);
System.out.println(data_in);
System.out.println(urlconnection);
```

Comment: I just don't understand, get us a jsFiddle

Answer (score 1):

Java won't load the page and execute the JS code it contains like a browser would do. All it will do is load the data sent by the server in the response.

If you want a programmable browser in Java, then look at Selenium or HtmlUnit.

Comment: How can I send data to server?? Let say I would like to use java to search stackoverflow at Google. And then show the first website's name at java. How can I do that?

Comment: Send data with what? Plain Java HttpUrlConnection? HtmlUnit? Selenium? Have you read the answer and read the documentation of HtmlUnit and Selenium?